# Kendo grid automatically scroll

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to auto scroll my grid into last added data. I extract this https://www.npmjs.com/package/kendo-grid-scroll. I call it in my dataBound method and do it like that

```
var kendoGridScroll = new KendoGridScroll.Model(e.sender, function(grid, row) {
    grid.select(row); //do whatever you want 
});
```

Finally in this line i get such error

> $grid.data is not a function

Do you know why it happend or you know any diffrent way to do auto scrroling kendo grid?

Comment: Why won't you try like the example in the lib's page and initiate the `KendoGridScroll` after the grid's initialization, and not inside `dataBound` ?

Comment: I have to scroll grid if data is load and open detatils of last added object.

Comment: Can you post your entire code ?

Comment: What you want to see my dataBound method, grid options or whole js file which is really large?

Comment: At least your grid initialization and dataBound with the scroll part only, i think.

Comment: Ok, so i edited my post

Comment: Well, I was in doubt if your code has `$grid` or not. It don't seems to have it. I wonder if the exception you're having is an internal exception of the plugin. Perhaps a misuse of the tool itself or even a bug. I'm not sure to tell you which one.

Comment: Maybe you know diffrent way to scroll grid automatically?

Comment: You want to scroll all the way down when data is loaded, or you really need to scroll to a specific item ?

Comment: It can be all the way, couse like i see latest item is allways on the down.

Comment: I resolve it. This method need jQuery object so i should call it like that
var kendoGridScroll = new KendoGridScroll.Model(e.sender,wrapper, function(grid, row) {
    grid.select(row); //do whatever you want 
});

Comment: Great. but, keep in mind that if my answer fits your needs and you won't use any other feature for that plugin, I recommend take my solution - which is much more short - instead of using an entire plugin for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is trick of how to scroll down a grid to its bottom:

```
var scrollGridDown = function() {
    var content = $(grid.element).find(".k-scrollbar").get(0);

    content.scrollTop = content.scrollHeight;
};
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/odEQU)